# How can i setup delegation with an HSM (Ledger, Trezor)?

Tags: ledger, hsm, setup, delegating, trezor

If I am a new user who wants to store my XTZ using a hardware wallet (like Ledger or Trezor T), what are the steps to set myself up with delegating those XTZ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when storing tezos using an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) one still needs to connect to a node in order to perform operations like transactions or [delegation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html?highlight=delegate#delegation). For this there is the choice between connecting to a local full node (see [here](https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/getting-started-with-tezos-on-the-ledger-nano-s-c011517b0f3c) or [there](https://medium.com/cryptium/how-to-delegate-tezzies-tezos-xtz-with-your-ledger-nano-s-with-initial-setup-screenshots-519c9ae6654f)) or wallet services that offer support for HSM, like [Tezbox](https://medium.com/@officialtezbox/hardware-wallets-69d27c470219), [Galleon](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Deployments/wiki/Galleon:-Releases) (as of now [Kukai](https://kukai.app/) does not support HSM I believe).

One can find a number of guides to help new Tezos holder get setup properly when they use HSM. The following articles describe the steps involved:

- [Here](https://medium.com/cryptium/how-to-store-your-tezos-xtz-in-your-ledger-nano-s-and-delegate-with-tezbox-wallet-8fb4ac2d3355)  or [here](https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/getting-started-with-tezos-on-the-ledger-nano-s-c011517b0f3c) if one stores their XTZ using a [Ledger nano S](https://www.ledger.fr/2019/01/23/tezos-wallet-app-is-now-available-to-download-on-ledger-live/)
- [There](https://medium.com/cryptium/how-to-delegate-tezzies-tezos-xtz-with-trezor-model-t-hardware-wallet-and-simplestaking-wallet-c2d9aa5b37b8) if one stores their XTZ using a [Trezor model T](https://wiki.trezor.io/Tezos_(XTZ))